# Does DMX 1-Step underlayment need to be screwed down onto concrete?

Tags: basement, flooring, underlayment

I am looking to use DMX 1-Step dimpled underlayment in my basement for a finishing project. I looked at the installation checklist and it does not seem to mention anything about how it attaches to what's below it - in my case it's concrete. Does it install in a floating fashion or should I be using tapcons to secure it down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the  [Installation Instructions](https://dmx1step.com/app/uploads/2020/01/DMX-1-Step-2.0-Installation-Checklist-1.pdf), it appears that it just floats, and is held down by the weight of the flooring.

Note the following two steps:

- If perimeter walls are unfinished, take DMX 1-StepTM 2.0 UNDERLAYMENT to foundation wall and seal with foam

and

- Tape the seams with DMX Joining Tape (tape along the length of the seam first, then tape across)

Comment: Thanks. I had seen the instructions and just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing any hidden assumptions. Any ideas why the product package includes both one sided seaming tape and a roll of double sided tape?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the product, but does it come in rolls?  You might use double side to  help it lay flat.

Comment: Understood, thank you for your help.